# iOS GameOver screen does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uikit

We have an error with our iOS game. The gameover screen (containing the score) doesn't come up after losing the game, as it just hangs up. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem and how can we fix this?

We are currently testing and we are not sure if this is the case because of the code or the test settings? But so far the Xcode doesn't show any errors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What game framework are you using?

Comment: I hope we are referring to GameKit in this case. There are many other frameworks installed such as Foundation. Hope that helps!

Comment: Not really.  GameKit provides support for games (Game Center etc.) however it's not a framework to build a game upon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Droppy. I have UIKit framework does that help?

Comment: Yes; I have editted your tags.  Please check them.

Comment: How do you present the GameOver screen? Push via navigation controller or bring view to front or else? Add your code.

Comment: yeah. Please provide more details. How are you presenting it. Code or storyboard?

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit for this game in addition to UIKit?

Comment: Yes we are using SpriteKit as well. The problem when the game is tested on iPad. We tested the game on the iPhone and it works just fine. Does that mean anything?

Answer (score 0):

**Open a view from a normal class:**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:StoryboardID];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Edit these strings to:
storyBoardName = The name of your storyboard.
storyBoardID = The StoryBoardID of your ViewController.

**Open a view from the AppDelegate**

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyBoardID];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Edit these strings to:
storyBoardName = The name of your storyboard.
storyBoardID = The StoryBoardID of your ViewController.

**Other information**

*How to get the storyBoardName?*
If your StoryBoard is called `Main.storyboard` Main is the title.
If your StoryBoard is called `MyName.storyboard` MyName is the title

*How to set a StoryBoardID?*
Select your ViewController. Your View must now be highlighted blue. Go to the identity inspector and under identity you'll find StoryBoardID. Set it to whatever you like.

*If it still doesn't work when you use this code you have put in the wrong variables, or there's an unknown error.*